# How to search if a row is a substring of another row of the same column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-string

I have a table that contains millions of rows for names of customers as a column. I want to find if a part of a name exists within another row in the same column.
E.g. If a row has value 'Roger Federer' and there are other rows with values, 'Roger' and 'Federer', I want the corresponding primary keys of all the three rows.

Comment: What did you try ? Do you have some code to post ?

Comment: Not yet, no. Cannot seem to zero in on a logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to construct a logic related to rows, `union` concepts may suit well,

by the way, in string operations we'd better use collations with patterns through `upper` or `lower` functions to satisfy *case-insensitivity*  for letters :

```
select id from customers where lower(name) like '%roger%' union all
select id from customers where lower(name) like '%federer%';
```

and no need to add ***already included*** *complete name* ( e.g. *Roger Federer* ).

**Edit :**
An [Alternative method](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/031d3/3) maybe the following :

```
  select distinct id
    from (select lower(regexp_substr('&str', '[^[:space:]-]+', 1, 1)) frst,
                 lower(regexp_substr('&str', '[^[:space:]-]+', 1, 2)) lst,
                 lower('&str') nm
            from customers) c1
   cross join customers c2
   where c1.frst like '%' || lower(c2.name) || '%'
      or c1.lst like '%' || lower(c2.name) || '%'
      or c1.nm like '%' || lower(c2.name) || '%';
```

by adding a search string(`'&str'`) to make the query more dynamic as you wish.
( when prompted enter Roger Federer for `str` substitution variable )

Comment: I want it to be dynamic rather than static.

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage the use of [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM   customers    
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (cust_name, 'roger|federer','i')
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f14da0/2)

More examples of REGEXP_LIKE usages can be found [here](http://ramkedem.com/en/oracle-regexp_like/)

Another option would be the use of OR

```
SELECT * 
    FROM   customers    
        WHERE LOWER(cust_name) LIKE LOWER('%roger%')
    OR LOWER(cust_name) LIKE LOWER('%federer%')
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f14da0/1)

Edit

With the use of JOIN, the search string is dynamic. If proper indexes are in place, then it would not have much impact.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   c1.*
FROM
   customers c1 
   JOIN
      customers c2
      ON ( LOWER(c1.cust_name) LIKE LOWER(c2.cust_name || '%') 
      AND c1.cust_id != c2.cust_id)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88749/23)

Edit 2

Perhaps something like the below

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   c1.cust_id,
   c1.cust_name,
   CASE
      WHEN
         LOWER(c1.cust_name) LIKE LOWER(c2.cust_name || '%') 
      THEN
         'Matched' 
      ELSE
         'Unmatched' 
   END
   ident 
FROM
   customers c1 
   JOIN
      customers c2 
      ON ( LOWER(c1.cust_name) LIKE LOWER(c2.cust_name || '%') 
      AND c1.cust_id != c2.cust_id)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88749/39)

Comment: This could work. However I need to add an identifier for all the matched cases in order to Group them. Any idea?

Comment: @MdDanishKhan Please provide sample data and expected output, you can do this by editing the question.

Comment: @MdDanishKhan I have updated my answer with an identifier. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use join same table twice (self join) to get output with below query,

```
select a.*, b.* 
  from tab1 a 
      , tab1 b
where ( a.fname like b.fname||'%' or a.lname like b.lname||'%')
  and a.id <> b.id
```

Comment: The column has more than a million names and the cost of the query would increase drastically if I use self join. Can you provide the solution with the help of a function or some other algorithm.

Comment: If you can Add function based index on the column can help improve the performance, but any wildcard will have performance issue